# Using normalizer with keyword data type in elastic search giving unexpected results

Tags: elasticsearch

I created an index as such

```
PUT twitter
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "normalizer": {
          "caseinsensitive_exact_match_normalizer": {
            "filter": "lowercase",
            "type": "custom"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "whitespace_lowercasefilter_analyzer": {
            "filter": "lowercase",
            "char_filter": "html_strip",
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "mappings": {
    "test" : {
      "properties": {
        "col1" : {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "col2" : {
          "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "caseinsensitive_exact_match_normalizer"
        }
      } 
    }

  }
}
```

then I inserted values in index as

```
POST twitter/test
{
  "col1" : "Dhruv",
  "col2" : "Dhruv"
}
```

then I query index as

```
GET twitter/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "col2": {
        "value": "DHRUV"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I get the results

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "twitter",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "AV9yNWQb3aJEm8NgRhd_",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "col1": "Dhruv",
          "col2": "Dhruv"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

as per my understaning, we should not get a result since term query ignores the analysis so it should search for `DHRUV`in inverted index and in index value stored should be `dhruv` since we used `caseinsensitive_exact_match_normalizer`. I am suspecting that term query doesn't ignore `normalizer`. Is that right?

I am using ES 5.4.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It seems it's normal](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/25487) for a `term` query to consider the normalizer when searching. But, as the issue linked previously, it's been decided this is not the expected behavior.

If you want to see what kind of query ES is rewritting yours to, you can use something like this:

```
GET /_validate/query?index=twitter&explain
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "col2": {
        "value": "DHRUV"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which will show you why you get those results:

```
  "explanations": [
    {
      "index": "twitter",
      "valid": true,
      "explanation": "col2:dhruv"
    }
  ]
```